# html2canavas error in mvc 4 project

Tags: javascript, getelementsbytagname, html2canvas

So here is what im trying to do: 
I have a page where the user sees a representation of a card after which the user clicks save card the following function is called and the data should return to my controller in order for me to save the card as an image. I use html2canvas for this and here is the code:

```
<div class="row download-card">
<div class="span12">
    <h2>Congratulations!</h2>
    <h3>You may download your MyCard</h3>
    <div id="card" class="card center">
        <ul>
            <li style="float: left;position: absolute;display: block;padding-top: 200px; padding-left: 200px;text-align: left;font-family:arial;color:white;font-size:x-large;">@name @lastname<span style="padding-left:90px;font-size:x-large; color:#ffffff;font-family:arial;">@CardNo</span></li>
            <li style="float: left;position: absolute;display: block;padding-top: 230px; padding-left: 200px;text-align: left;color:white;">Member since: @yearRegistered <span style="color:white; padding-left:10px;font-family:arial;">Valid Thru: @validThru</span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <button class="btn" type="button" onclick="screenShot('card')">Download</button>
</div>
</div>

<script src="~/assets/userpanel/js/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


function screenShot(id) {
html2canvas(id, {
    proxy: "https://html2canvas.appspot.com/query",
    onrendered: function(canvas) {

        var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        var output = img.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
        var output = encodeURIComponent(img);

        var Parameters = "image=" + output + "&filedir=" + cur_path;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Profile/savecardPNG",
            data: Parameters,
            success : function(data)
            {
                console.log("screenshot done");
            }
        }).done(function() {
            //$('body').html(data);
        });

    }
});
}
</script>
```

so a button on the page calls the function screenshot('card') and this could fires up but i get the following error in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object c has no method 'getElementsByTagName'
>   html2canvas.js:2191
>   _html2canvas.Preload html2canvas.js:2191

(anonymous function)

Please let me know whats happening?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure html2canvas requires a dom element, not a string id.  Try using:

```
function screenShot(id) {
    var elem = document.getElementById( id );
    html2canvas( elem, {...});
}
```

Comment: I just checked for broken html and fortunately there are non!

Comment: The HTML you posted above is missing a closing div tag.  if that's not the full html, you should edit your post to include the full html, or better yet make a jsfiddle so we can see it.

Comment: oh my bad, I missed the end div tag while pasting! so the html is just fine.